# What product would you recommend for coating/rubberizing metal furniture to be placed on a plastic deck?

Tags: deck, furniture, scratches

I have a new plastic/composite deck (Azek) and have a metal bench that was on the previous deck.  I don't want to scratch up my nice new deck and have watched a few youtube videos on rubberizing or coating tools with different prodcucts.

However, this is going to be a slightly higher wear situation and I don't need waterproofing.  With those factors in mind is there a product/process you would use to keep the evil metal legs of a bench off of a pristine composite deck?

Comment: There are many different types of floor protectors for legs, from the slip on types to pads, to homemade(a piece of carpet).  A picture of the bench/legs might help, but usually shopping/recommendation questions are not on topic here, but how to protect the deck might be.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.homedepot.com/b/Paint-Industrial-Paint-Rubberized-Coatings/FLEX-SEAL-FAMILY-OF-PRODUCTS/N-5yc1vZc8kfZrem
This one has a clear.

I've never had any experience with doing something like this but I am confident it would work.

I have been a retail paint store manager for 21 years and I think I'll even start recommending this to my customers who have this issue. Thanks for the learning experience!

Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with or stand to monetize from Home Depot, PlastiDip, or Flex-Seal.
I'm going to do some of my own testings.

Comment: Unfortunately, Plastidip shreds easily under friction and pressure. It will sometimes work itself off tool handles when subject to extreme forces applied by hand. In the OP's circumstance, sliding the furniture along a surface is likely to abrade the coating.

Comment: I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use chair tips.  these are plastic covers for the metal legs of your furniture.